# Excel VBA Input and Output automation from and to a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to automate moving data from a range (A2:A869) into a cell (G2)and then copy the output (G5) into a corresponding range (B2:B869). In simple terms I want to automate copying a single value into a cell, and then copying the value from a different cell, and then repeat 869 times. My sloppy code looks like this. There has to be an easier way than writing the same code 869 times.

Thanks for your help!

````
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Paste to range G2 on selectedSheet from range A2 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("G2").copyFrom(selectedSheet.getRange("A2"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
    // Paste to range B2 on selectedSheet from range G5 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("B2").copyFrom(selectedSheet.getRange("G5"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.values, false, false);
    // Paste to range G2 on selectedSheet from range A3 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("G2").copyFrom(selectedSheet.getRange("A3"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
    // Paste to range B3 on selectedSheet from range G5 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("B3").copyFrom(selectedSheet.getRange("G5"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.values, false, false);
}```
````

Comment: If you continue with the VBA route all you need to do is add some type of loop, probably `For Each...Next`.

Comment: The other option is to put your (I'm assuming) formula that is calculating G5 into all of your cells B2:B869...

Comment: Shouldn't the tag be `office-js` rather than `VBA`?  Ok, just checked - `office-js` tag not available in SuperUser (is in SO).